# Double Title Suffix

Tags: magento-1.8, seo

I don't use any suffixes for any title. In system -> design -> html head the suffix and prefix fields are blank.

But in Google my pages are shown with double suffix! "-eshops.gr eshops.gr".

Comment: in which page shows double title?

Comment: if you search for "site:eshops.gr" in Google you will see a lot of pages having that "-eshops.gr eshops.gr" suffix. Product pages, Cms Pages, Category pages. Everything...

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a Google Search related question.

Your site, from what I can see from the frontend, has nothing wrong in respect of what you are asking. It appears that you've been playing around with the suffixes in the backend. Keep in mind that google does not crawl your site daily, so changes you may make in meta tags will show after a period of 1 to 15 days.

For a better management of what google does with magento, I suggest you open a [Google Webmaste account](http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/) and submit a sitemap.

In order to create the sitemap in magento, go to `Catalog->Google Sitemap` and `Add sitemap`. I guess in your case it will be `Κατάλογος->Χάρτης Ιστοτόπου Google` και `Εισαγωγή Χάρτη Ιστοτόπου`.

Now you can open the created xml file and see what you submit to google.

Answer (score 1):

What follows is entirely my opinion because I have no idea how the Google algorithm works, but it kind of makes sense.
Let's take this page for example. `http://www.eshops.gr/photovoltaic-panels.html`.
It has the title `Φωτοβολταϊκά πλαίσια/πάνελ τιμές - eshops.gr`.
And your homepage has the title `>Eshops.gr - Φωτοβολταικα τιμές, αγορά | Πανελ - Πλαισια | Αυτόνομα Συστήματα | Inverters | Ανεμογεννήτριες | Μπαταρίες | Φωτοβολταϊκό Συστημα | Νέα`.

Most probably Google appends in it's listing a part  of the title of the homepage (or full title) for the rest of the pages.

So in your case you get the first part of the homepage title `Eshops.gr` appended to the `Φωτοβολταϊκά πλαίσια/πάνελ τιμές - eshops.gr` and you end up with duplicate `Eshops.gr`.

My conclusion is based on the following website. `www.arnia.ro` (that's the company I work for, no publicity intended used just as an example because it was handy).

If you search for `site:arnia.ro` you will get for example this page in the results `Services - ARNIA Software` ([www.arnia.ro/services](http://www.arnia.ro/services)).
The title of the page is `Services` (not the best, maybe we should work on SEO).
But in the Google list it has the title `Services - {THE TITLE OF THE HOMEPAGE}` (which is `Arnia Software`).

I don't think you will get a clear and valid answer unless someone from Google decides to let us in on how the search algorithm works.